# Какое окончание слова правильное: остались в бессиль(и), или остались в бессиль(е)

Tags: орфография

Как правильно:
1. Остались в бессильи
2. Остались в бессилье

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***в бессилье*** (**основное окончание Е**, предложный падеж для существительного ср. рода 2-го склонения)

Примеры в Нацкорпусе:http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E2+%E1%E5%F1%F1%E8%EB%FC%E5

**Примечание**

**Окончание И** (в форме П.п. и Д.п. для сущ. 1-го и 2-го скл.) является исключением для слов **с основой на И**, сравнить: *в молчан**ье** — в молчан**ии**.*

Сочетаемость выражения ***остались в бессилье*** вызывает сомнение. Можно сказать: *остановились в бессилье*.

Answer (score 1):

А о чём вы хотели сказать? 
О действии: 
1) остались в бессильи - что-то **в самом бессильи** еще действует, но не так явно, сильно (остались возможности к повтору). 
2) остались в бессилии - что-то ушло вместе с потухшим бессилием.

О состоянии: 
1) остались в бессилье - кто-то попал в оное состояние и остается в нём; 
2) остались в бессилье - кто-то сбросил с себя состояние немощности и оставил в нём, например, плохие мысли.

Comment: О состоянии, наверно. Они остались в бессилье, в одиночестве, одни, без помощи и т.д.

Comment: Хороший вопрос задали. Надо взять на заметку слово "бессилие", у него в Предложном падеже действуют три разных окончания!